Can anything be perfect, or is perfection merely an illusion?
To claim that something is perfect, it must be compared to a standard of perfection. But how can we ever be certain that the standard itself is truly perfect?

Mathematical circles are perfect as are all platonic forms. They are the standard of perfection, so says Plato. We can be certain because they are defined as such. And if a standard is not specified there is no point talking about perfection, it cannot even be an illusion.

@andrós I would say rather that Conifold makes a category error of mixing up contingent truths from necessary ones. Acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 m/s². You could arguably stretch the single digit significance to 5 digits: 9.78032 m/s². After 12-15 digits this stops making sense. OTOH the digits of π have been worked out to a thousand or million or a billion. And each digit is as accurate as any other

To see why the question is non-sensical, replace "perfect" with "red":"To claim that something is red, it must be compared to a standard of redness. But how can we ever be certain that the standard itself is truly red?" Even if 'red' made sense for standards it would be a separate property from the red it standardizes, and a standard does not need to be 'red' to be a standard of red. Not only do we not need to be "certain" about it, we need not consider it at all. And if we choose to do it then we need to define what "perfect standards" mean, but then we can be certain because we defined it.

@Conifold I have a feeling you are reading the question too literalistically. Try reading Standard of perfection(redness) instead as perfect(red) standard

Yes, something can be perfect. First, we need to determine whom it need be perfect to or what it need be perfect at or as. Is the person I have lived with the last 20 years, perfect for me? Yes. Even the supposed shortcomings challenge me, perfectly.

The classical sense of the word "perfect" basically means "complete," or lacking nothing.  If this is the sense, I think you're hitting on something subtle but profound.  While we can easily understand perfection in theory, I doubt we can ever fully measure it in practice.  We can easily measure when something is imperfect by imagining better; but what if we can't imagine anything better?  How do we know the limitation isn't with our imaginations?  I'd argue that in almost all cases of any complexity, the only one with access to the requisite middle knowledge (or all the "what-ifs") to definitely place the stamp of "perfection" on it is God.
Here's a silly example, which is admittedly entirely subjective, but which I think gets the point across.  :)  Let's say you have a cheese pizza about to go into the oven.  You know immediately that it isn't perfect; it needs pepperonis.  Everyone knows that no pizza is complete without pepperonis.  So you throw some pepperonis onto the pizza and put it into the oven, and it comes out a few minutes later steaming hot.  Is the pizza perfect?  Yes.  Wait, no, you need to add hot peppers.  Now it's perfect!  Or is it?  Maybe you're just not thinking of something that could make it even better, tastier, more complete.  Maybe some day a friend will show you some new  seasoning that will surpass your hot peppers.  How can you ever know for sure?
So in my opinion, what you're hitting on is an interesting uniqueness with the concept of perfection specifically.  In most cases, the standard is accessible in theory but inaccessible in practice, given the inordinate knowledge and computation required.  In most cases, I'd argue that the only one with that kind of intellectual firepower is God.

Caution not to be fooled out by language.
The standard is the definition. It makes no sense to apply the standard to itself. That’s a category error.
Example: At the time when length was defined by the standard meter at Paris, how to ensure that the standard meter had exactly the length of 1 meter?

Your example fails egregiously. First the meter was defined in terms of the earth's circumference, then in terms of a standard rod. Nowadays in terms of the speed of light. Clearly, the standard was changed because it was not good enough

@Rushi IMO you mix up the “standard for 1 meter” and the “standard for a definition”.

Yes, I hear you. You are making a category error out of this. But its not. This is what the question is about and your example proves the point of the question better than the question itself did

this is, as usual, a good answer by jo. no idea why it's downvoted
